# Accidentally deleted file in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I accidentally had one of my files selected in a project in Xcode and pushed delete and it was deleted. Anyone know how to recover it? It won't let me undo. Please help.

Comment: it is in the trash now. you can look it up there

Comment: take a look at the trash or use spotlight to search it

Comment: Its not in the trash or coming up when I use spotlight

Comment: This is why you need to use source code control and Time Machine (or other backups) and snapshots.

Comment: Did you press `Move to Trash` or `Remove Reference`?

Answer (score 10):

The file itself is not deleted, it is simply removed from the Project Navigator. 
To add it back, go to 
File -> Add files to "projectName" 
and select the missing file, after having navigated to the project's folder if needed.
Or simply hit cmd+z

Answer (score 8):

May be its too late but for someone else it might be good to know, that's why I am answering it.

1. Go to **File** >>> **Add Files'Your Project Name'** there will be a list of all files which have been removed from project, **select** and **add** them back.
2. Now these files are back in project, but they don't have any **reference** yet so xCode will give you error saying "Storyboard do not have any file of this name", now you have to **add references**, for this just **right click** on that missing files and **add that file to project**.

**NOTE**: If you have removed files directly to **trash** then **restore** from trash and **repeat second step** to add **reference** back in project.

Comment: forget one thing to mention, that if you have also removed files from trash then there's no way to get them back because now they are permanently gone, in order to avoid these accidents in future use github in xCode and commit changes as much as possible.

Answer (score 5):

This file should be in the trash folder, look in that folder or you can search via apple spotlight.

Comment: Its not in the trash or coming up when I use spotlight

Comment: This is an incorrect answer; the deleted file is not in trash.

Comment: @Zorayr It is correct. Normally deleted files within xCode are beeing moved to the Macs trash.

Comment: @Akaino This does not apply to files that XCode automatically deletes without warning.

Answer (score 4):

The following steps will allow you to recover (a) deleted file(s):

1. Click on the **trash** icon on the bottom right
2. Search for the file(s) and move it back into your project folder
3. In **XCode**, go to **File**, **Add Files to ...**, then select the file(s) you've just restored

Comment: God bless you!!

Comment: This did not work at all. The files I put into the xcplayground contents are just GONE.

Answer (score 0):

There are some files that XCode deletes utterly without warning. These files are permanently deleted unless you have a backup.